# Who to contact to amend Tagore's Jana Gana Mana?

Tags: bengali-language, rabindranath-tagore

In the Indian national anthem, Jana Gana Mana, I propose replacing the word Sindh (the province is in Pakistan since 1947) with Isaanya (north east India) to reflect contemporary geographical realities of India. Importantly, poetic meter remains unchanged. So, the mellifluous tune of the Indian national anthem can still be retained.

> Jana-gaṇa-mana-adhinâyaka jaya he
>
> Bhârata-bhâgya-vidhâtâ
>
> Pãnjâb-**Isaanya**-Gujarâta-Marâṭhâ
>
> Drâviḍa-Utkala-Bãga
>
> Vĩdhya-Himâcala-Yamunâ-Gãgâ
>
> Ucchala-jaladhi-tarãga
>
> Tava[k] shubha nâme jâge,
>
> Tava[k] shubha âshîṣa mẫge,
>
> Gâhe tava[k] jaya-gâthâ.
>
> Jana-gaṇa-mãgaladâyaka jaya he
>
> Bhârata-bhâgya-vidhâtâ.
>
> Jaya he, jaya he, jaya he,
>
> Jaya jaya jaya jaya he!**

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about modifying/creating literature, instead of analyzing/studying it.

Comment: @bobble Why treat this as "modifying/creating literature"? The suggestion may be questionable but seems to fit [tag:publishing]; emending existing texts is something editors do and does not "create" new literature.

Comment: I voted to close because this question is more political in nature than anything else. I don't think we would accept questions about who to contact about the changing of the wording of a law. Similarly, I would think  that the a National Anthem would be selected and regulated by the government (although (I am not overly familiar with India's laws or governmen.t)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a political statement.

Answer (score 1):

Given its role as a national anthem, presumably a national political process can be followed to amend its lyrics. That doesn't change what Tagore wrote, but it changes the anthem. For comparison, Australia's national anthem lyrics have changed [multiple times since its adoption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advance_Australia_Fair) in 1974, due to changing social attitudes.

So option one is for new lyrics to be declared by parliamentary legislation, or by decree of the president of the Republic of India.

A second and perhaps complementary option is for the new lyrics to be promulgated through a process of political advocacy and of individuals singing the alternative lyrics on those formal occasions when the anthem is sung.